# CORS Error when uploading larger file (MultipartFile) in Spring Boot Web API

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, servlets, cors, multipart

I have the below API to save MultipartFile. I am able to save files if the file size is below the defined limit.

```
@PostMapping("/attachments")
    @Operation(summary = "save attachments")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Attachment>> saveAttachments(@RequestParam ("files") MultipartFile[] files,@RequestParam ("id") Long id) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(myservice.saveAttachment(id, files));
    }
```

Below is my properties file:

```
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold=2KB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=200MB
```

Now, If I upload anything below 10MB it works fine without any errors. But, when I try to upload any file above 10MB then I am getting a CORS policy error (I have already defined CORS policy).

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8002/api/attachments' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I am handling file size exception and getting below exception handling message in backend:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.web.multipart.MaxUploadSizeExceededException: Maximum upload size exceeded]
```

Answer (score 0):

this is maybe due to pre-flight request

> A CORS preflight request is an HTTP OPTIONS request that a web browser sends to a server before it sends an actual request. The purpose of the preflight request is to determine whether the server will allow the actual request to be made.

so your browser sends a preflight request "containing content length header" to ask the server if it will allow this request, the server checks that the size is bigger than what it allows so it says no I will not allow this request.

your fix would be to edit application.properties to support whatever sizes you want

here I set max-size to be 1GB per request

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=1000MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=1000MB
```

Comment: Okay, could you please suggest possible solutions for this?

Comment: Have you checked my question? I already have these defined. The problem is what if the user uploads a file larger than max-file-size? CORS error coming only in later condition.

Comment: you define properties such as max-request-size to tell the server to reject very big requests, then it rejects it on preflight causing cors error. if you wanna let all sizes go by and never reject it, just set them to 100GB or whatever you want

Comment: Thanks, but, I am looking for more effective solution. We should handle that CORS error and display an appropriate error message for user.