# Big data returns CORS Error TypeError: Failed to Fetch not consuming the api

Tags: c#, .net, cors, blazor-webassembly

I'm currently consuming a post api using .net 5 with front end as blazor wasm, on browser it returns an error

> Access to fetch at 'https://localhost:44328/Company/' from origin
> 'https://localhost:5000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

so i tried setting up a breakpoint on the webapi in the controller layer if it really passes through

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<CompanyModel >> SaveCompany([FromBody] CompanyModel companyModel)
        {
              // break point 
        }
```

unfortunately it didn't so I checked my configuration with cors which looks fine

Configuration:

```
app.UseCors("AllowAll");
```

ConfigurationServices:

```
services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("AllowAll", builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader();
            }));
```

So I thought maybe I'm passing a bad data into a string content like messing up the serialization

```
public async Task<CompanyModel> SaveCompanyDetails(CompanyModel companyModel)
        {
            CompanyModel savedCompany = null;
                var entityjson = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(companyModel ), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(string.Empty, entityjson);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    savedCompany = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CompanyModel>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                }

            return savedCompany;
        }
```

Its when I realize I was passing huge amount of string content with byte size of **30026250**

I backed this up by trying to lessen the number of data I'm passing

```
public class CompanyModel {
..
public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
..
}
```

Upon testing when the Employee count is above 80 this is when I encounter the system.exception TypeError: Failed to Fetch, but less than or byte size below 30MB it works it hits the breakpoint.

Is there limit to a string content? How can I increase that limit?

Comment: 30MB isn't big data in any sense and CORS errors are thrown *before* any request is made. CORS is enforced by the browser. The browser itself checks the CORS headers it received when the site/SPA application was loaded and refuses to make the call if the URL isn't allowed by the CORS policy

Comment: `it hits the breakpoint.` instead of looking at breakpoints use the browser's Developer Tools and check the Network tab and Console. In the network tab you'll see that in successful calls, there's an OPTIONS call (pre-flight check) to determine if the actual call can be made and *then* comes the actual call. 30MB is pretty big for a non-file request though and either the actual web server or any proxies in front of it may reject the POST request. Don't rush to disable CORS without understanding the cause of the error

Comment: OP says that browser returns that error message. His CORS configuration is not the real problem.

Comment: @Smashoverflow and where are CORS checks done? Shouldn't the OP check the actual requests and failures before making assumptions?

Comment: I said that his CORS config is not the problem. Read OP post again and you will realize that the service does not work only when the data is huge. So, it is probably a timeout exception.

Comment: @Yzak did you check the Network tab? What does it show when you make this request? Also, why such a large request? Even if it succeeds, it consumes a lot of resources and allocates a lot of objects, both for serialization and *de*serialization. You could use a more efficient format like protobuf or send the data over multiple requests. After all, Employee and Company are different entities, even if they're related. You could also use a streaming protocol like gRPC-Web or SignalR to send a stream of objects to the server instead of one huge request

Comment: @Yzak APIs and document databases either don't allow or severely restrict such huge request because they harm scalability by eating up RAM and CPU that could be used to serve other requests. Even if you find the server setting that will allow big client requests, it's probably better to rethink the API.

Comment: It is not a database problem, Panagitis. Read again OP post. His service works with data.

Comment: You're making a lot of unfounded assumptions. Timeouts when CORS is mentioned. Or databases (where did that come from?). If you actually bothered to check the error you'd find a lot of similar SO posts, that CORS policies *can* be affected by request size, that some proxies and servers *cause* CORS errors if there's a request limit. *Think Horses, not Zebras*

Comment: A CORS error was also thrown with large requests in [this Github issue](https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-upload/issues/165). In that case the error was cause due to a limit on the NGINX proxy in front of the API service. There's [a similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76614231/cors-error-when-uploading-larger-file-multipartfile-in-spring-boot-web-api)  for *Java*. The answer explains that a pre-flight check *can* include the size and the server *can* reject it

Comment: @Yzak The [MDN docs on preflight requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) explain that the browser sends an OPTIONS request and the server responds with what's allowed. That's why you need to check the Network tab to see what's sent and received before you make any assumptions

Comment: Yep, Network tab is useful for testing purpose. But OP shared the error message from console.... OP should configure HttpClient and/or catch exceptions while using HttpClient.

Comment: please read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-7.0 and undrestand if have another error you see cors error in browser too check your code mayba have another error.

Comment: The call to UseCors must be placed after UseRouting, but before UseAuthorization.

Answer (score 0):

Can you attempt to add:
`[EnableCors("AllowAll")]`

Above the endpoint you're trying to give access to?

Like so:

```
        [EnableCors("AllowAll")]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<CompanyModel >> SaveCompany([FromBody] CompanyModel companyModel)
        {
              // break point 
        }
```

If this works, I'd think that the default policy is being incorrectly configured maybe in Program.cs,

Perhaps being called in the wrong middleware ordering:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#middleware-order
Meaning it must be between routing and authorization.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably hitting the default max request size length in [kestrel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-6.0#kestrel-maximum-request-body-size) which is around 30MB.
Try increasing the mar request size (see the referenced doc for details).